# How to test xamarin test cloud? Getting Timed out waiting Error in below code

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, cloud

I have problem with Xamarin Test Cloud. I have app in my project folder, which name "anyapp.apk". My device run good with others project. And I see that app is load on device however and any test not running.  The App was test on samsung g 3 and nexus 6. If somebody during running test tap to app that test passed.

My test settings

```
Tests.cs

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Xamarin.UITest;
using Xamarin.UITest.Android;
using Xamarin.UITest.Queries;

namespace AnyAppAndroid_Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        AndroidApp app;

        [SetUp]
        public void BeforeEachTest ()
        {
            app = ConfigureApp
                .Android
                .ApiKey("my_key")
                .ApkFile ("anyapp.apk")
                .StartApp ();
        }

        [Test]
        public void AppLaunches ()
        {
            app.Screenshot ("First screen.");
        }
    }

}
```

My exception

```
SetUp : System.TimeoutException : Timed out waiting...

Trace of stack

  at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.WaitForHelper.WaitFor (System.Func`1 predicate, System.String timeoutMessage, Nullable`1 timeout, Nullable`1 retryFrequency, Nullable`1 postTimeout) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp..ctor (IAndroidAppConfiguration appConfiguration) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AndroidAppConfigurator.StartApp (AppDataMode appDataMode) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Anyapp_Tests.Tests.BeforeEachTest () [0x0001c] in /Users/myuser/Desktop/projects/app/anyapp/AnyAppAndroid_Tests/AnyAppAndroid_Tests/Tests.cs:28 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00054] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr2/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.2/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:230
```

I have connection with internet. My line running good and devices ( I test on two devices ). I tried close xamarin and start repeatedly a few of  times.

Cheers

Comment: could you fix that issue? I am facing the same in XTC! Thanks in advance